# Как настроить права на чтение/запись Laravel

Tags: linux, laravel, docker

Пожалуйста помоги. Я бьюсь над этой проблемой уже битый день.
Я перепробовал множество ответов из Интернета, в том числе и со Stackoverflow, но никак не могу решить следующую проблему.

Есть проект на Laravel, окружение в Docker: NGINX, PHP-FPM, MYSQL, REDIS. Мой docker-compose.yml имеет следующий вид:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./docker/nginx
        depends_on:
            - php-fpm
        environment:
            - TZ=Europe/Moscow
        networks:
            - sail
        ports:
            - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTPS_PORT}:443"
            - "${NGINX_HOST_HTTP_PORT}:80"
        volumes:
            - ${NGINX_SSL_PATH}:/etc/nginx/ssl
            - ./:/var/www/myproject
            - ${NGINX_HOST_LOG_PATH}:/var/log/nginx
            - ${NGINX_SITES_PATH}:/etc/nginx/sites-available

    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: ./docker/php-fpm
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/myproject
        networks:
            - sail
        expose:
            - 9000
        environment:
            - TZ=Europe/Moscow


    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - redis-cli
                - ping
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    networks:
        sail:
            driver: bridge
    volumes:
        sail-mysql:
            driver: local
        sail-redis:
            driver: local
```

Dockerfile NGINX выглядит так:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --update add logrotate \
    && apk add --no-cache openssl \
    && apk add --no-cache bash

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

RUN set -x ; \
    addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
    adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER=php-fpm
ARG PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT=9000

# Create 'myapp' file used from 'logrotate'
RUN touch /var/log/myproject

# Copy 'logrotate' config file
COPY logrotate/nginx /etc/logrotate.d/

# Set upstream conf and remove the default conf
RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server ${PHP_UPSTREAM_CONTAINER}:${PHP_UPSTREAM_PORT}; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf \
    && rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

#ADD ./startup.sh /opt/startup.sh
#RUN sed -i 's/\r//g' /opt/startup.sh
#CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/startup.sh"]

EXPOSE 80 81 443
```

PHP-FRPM Dockerfile имеет также такой вид:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

MAINTAINER svinpauk78@gmail.com

ENV COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT='-1'

WORKDIR /var/www/messenger

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes --no-install-recommends \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libz-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        openssh-server \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        git \
        cron \
        nano \
        libxml2-dev \
        libreadline-dev \
        libgmp-dev \
        mariadb-client \
        unzip \
        jpegoptim \
        optipng \
        pngquant \
        gifsicle

# Install soap extention
RUN docker-php-ext-install soap

# Install for image manipulation
RUN docker-php-ext-install exif

...


#####################################
# PHPRedis:
#####################################
RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

#####################################
# Imagick:
#####################################

RUN pecl install imagick && \
    docker-php-ext-enable imagick

#####################################
# GD:
#####################################

# Install the PHP gd library
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd

#####################################
# xDebug:
#####################################

# Install the xdebug extension
RUN pecl install xdebug

#####################################
# PHP Memcached:
#####################################

# Install the php memcached extension
RUN pecl install memcached && docker-php-ext-enable memcached

#####################################
# Composer:
#####################################

# Install composer and add its bin to the PATH.
RUN curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    echo "export PATH=${PATH}:/var/www/vendor/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
# Source the bash
RUN . ~/.bashrc

#####################################
# Laravel Schedule Cron Job:
#####################################

RUN echo "* * * * * www-data /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1"  >> /etc/cron.d/laravel-scheduler
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/laravel-scheduler

#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Final Touch
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

ADD ./laravel.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

#####################################
# Aliases:
#####################################
# docker-compose exec php-fpm dep --> locally installed Deployer binaries
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/vendor/bin/dep "$@"' > /usr/bin/dep
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/dep
# docker-compose exec php-fpm art --> php artisan
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan "$@"' > /usr/bin/art
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/art
# docker-compose exec php-fpm migrate --> php artisan migrate
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan migrate "$@"' > /usr/bin/migrate
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/migrate
# docker-compose exec php-fpm fresh --> php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan migrate:fresh --seed' > /usr/bin/fresh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/fresh
# docker-compose exec php-fpm t --> run the tests for the project and generate testdox
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan config:clear\n/var/www/vendor/bin/phpunit -d memory_limit=2G --stop-on-error --stop-on-failure --testdox-text=tests/report.txt "$@"' > /usr/bin/t
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/t
# docker-compose exec php-fpm d --> run the Laravel Dusk browser tests for the project
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan config:clear\n/bin/bash\n/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/artisan dusk -d memory_limit=2G --stop-on-error --stop-on-failure --testdox-text=tests/report-dusk.txt "$@"' > /usr/bin/d
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/d

RUN rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

# Add user for laravel application
#RUN groupadd -g 1000 www-data
#RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www-data www-data

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data . /var/www/messenger

# Change current user to www-data
USER www-data

#COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
#RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
#RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh /
#ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Проект собирается, запускается отлично. Я работаю на сервере из под пользователя root. Далее я дал все необходимые права и добавил пользователя www-data на свой сервер следующим образом:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/myproject
sudo usermod -a -G www-data $USER
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/myproject/storage
```

Далее я установил библиотеку для Laravel - [Spatie Media Library](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction), которая предназначена для работы с изображениями и другими файлами в проекте.

Проблема: при загрузке файлов на сервер у них слетают права на чтение и прочитать их становится невозможно. Клиент получает ошибку 404 и все. Хотя файл на сервере есть. Файл можно прочитать и загрузить с сервера только если я снова выполню команду:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/myproject/storage
```

Когда снова загрузить новые файлы на сервер, у них снова сбрасываются права. Я выполнил команду ls -l storage/app/public/uploads (директория для сохранения загружаемых файлов) и вот что она выводит (красным отмечены новые загруженные файлы)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответсвенно эти файлы снова нельзя прочитать. Как мне исправить данную проблему, чтобы новые загружаемые файлы на сервер можно было без проблем прочитать и у них не *слетали* права? Что я делаю не так?

На всякий случай прикреплю свой конфиг filesystem в Laravel
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй добавить в свой конфиг `media` вот это значение `'visibility' => 'public',`

Comment: @Knyaz71, добавил, но теперь выскакивает exception: mkdir(): Permission denied, но папка создается и файлы из нее читаются.

Comment: Тут уже не знаю... может среди родительский папок у какой-то права... ограниченные (по умолчанию, у папок обычно 755 стоит)